# Favorite Questions and Answers from the third quarter of 2015

Tags: discussion, blog

Please link to your favorite questions and answers which were either asked or answered from July 1st 2015 through September 30 2015.

**They don't have to be *your* questions and answers.**

Your answers will be compiled into a blog post like previous [quarterly posts](http://scifi.blogoverflow.com/category/qotw/).

I will be using DavRob60's queries for a baseline, but I really appreciate people voicing the ones they really enjoyed. Maybe you feel like you answered one really well, even if it didn't receive a lot of votes. Let me know about it.

- [Questions with most **Votes** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106579/questions-with-most-votes-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015/07/01)
- [Questions with most **View** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106705/questions-with-most-view-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015/07/01)
- [Questions with **best answer** created within 3 month range](http://data.stackexchange.com/science%20fiction%20and%20fantasy/query/106709/questions-with-best-answer-created-within-3-month-range?StartDate=2015/07/01)

Comment: [*All* Questions created in **Q3 - 2015**](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/365684/questions-created-in-quarter-range?Quarter=3&Year=2015)

Comment: [*All* Answers created in **Q3 - 2015**](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/292102/answers-created-in-q2-2015?Quarter=3&Year=2015)

Comment: @Mooz this is a highlight reel, not all 67000 slides from your aunt's vacation.

Answer (score 9):

### Questions

I think Hannover Fist deserves a special mention for the inventiveness and charm of his question about management policy:

- [Could I fake death to stop being Force-choked?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102822/could-i-fake-death-to-stop-being-force-choked/102826#102826)

And I rather liked Praxis' question which was both topical and amusing:

- [Which 2015 technologies were correctly predicted by Back to the Future II?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95971/which-2015-technologies-were-correctly-predicted-by-back-to-the-future-ii)

### Answers

Not to blow my own trumpet, but I thought [my own answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/96052/20774) to Slytherincess' deceptively simple question was very good:

- [Did J.K. Rowling give two or more unrelated characters the same first name in any of the 10 books?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96049/did-j-k-rowling-give-two-or-more-unrelated-characters-the-same-first-name-in-an)

and the variety of **quality answers** to this question about science fiction is worthy of a mention:

- [Which Sci-fi universe uses the most forms of FTL (Faster Than Light)?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96389/which-sci-fi-universe-uses-the-most-forms-of-ftl-faster-than-light)

Answer (score 7):

I'm sure this doesn't really need to be said, but [your answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/100281/5184) to the [Who are these DC superheroes](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100278/5184) for its sheer and ridiculous overachieving.

Answer (score 7):

Here are my nominations, in no particular order:

## Questions

- N_Soong's question [Is there anyone Strickland doesn't think is a slacker?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95624/) made me laugh
- I enjoyed Richard's question [Who (or what) is Unbreakable?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95882/), which deconstructs something that might be taken for granted otherwise
- Dr R Dizzle's question [Does the general public know who superheroes really are in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100804/), for which he offered his own answer, is interesting and informative
- ThePopMachine's question [In Star Trek, do the Greek gods lack nipples?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102947/) may have caused SFF:SE to "jump the shark", but it brought up some interesting facts about 1960s US television
- Without any intention to self-promote, I was quite happy with my question [Is the ending of Minority Report halo-induced?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95944/), which generated a lot of nice discussion

## Answers

- Richard's answer to [Did Indiana Jones affect the outcome of Raiders of the Lost Ark?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97162/) is brilliant
- Wad Cheber's answer to [Which 2015 technologies were correctly predicted by Back to the Future II?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95971/) gets a mandatory inclusion, because he really went the distance!
- JMFB gave a perfect answer to [What exactly is cellular peptide cake?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99116/)
- Jason Baker did stellar work on [Why are there so many 47s?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97166/)
- I think I ought to mention the ThePopMachine's answer to [What's the relationship among the many uses of the name "Praxis" in sci-fi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99720/), given that he *wrote a poem about me* within it
- Again without self-promoting, I want to mention my answer to [Who wrote "Ode to Spot" and Data's other poem?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96879/), because it gave me an excuse to pester Star Trek writer and producer Brannon Braga

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the props!

Answer (score 5):

I liked [Why did Agent Smith & co. pursue (pre escaped) Neo through the Matrix instead of going to his pod?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/93423/why-did-agent-smith-co-pursue-pre-escaped-neo-through-the-matrix-instead-of) most of all my questions, and I'm too jealous to nominate anything better.

Answer (score 5):

## Questions

- Praxis' '[Why are there so many 47s?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97166/why-are-there-so-many-47s)'
- Praxis' '[When and why did the Enterprise get balls?'](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94273/when-and-why-did-the-enterprise-get-balls)'
- Major Stackings' '[What, aside from binocular vision, eye count, and goggle style, is the difference between 1 eyed and 2 eyed minions?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96469/what-aside-from-binocular-vision-eye-count-and-goggle-style-is-the-differenc)'
- Chris' '[Trying to remember a dinosaur book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102109/trying-to-remember-a-dinosaur-book)'
- The Pop Machine's '[Which Star Trek character appeared on screen with the most different ranks?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99468/which-star-trek-character-appeared-on-screen-with-the-most-different-ranks)'

## Answers

- JMFB's answer to '[Why weren't civilians evacuated before the fleet at Wolf 359 engaged the borg?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97523/why-werent-civilians-evacuated-before-the-fleet-at-wolf-359-engaged-the-borg/97534#97534)'
- Wad Cheber's answer (that gives you a finger-cramp from scrolling it's so detailed) to '[Why does the Ring have such an obsessive possessive effect?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95351/why-does-the-ring-have-such-an-obsessive-possessive-effect/95487#95487)'
- Himarm's answer to '[Do the Borg have any plans after assimilating all they want?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102424/do-the-borg-have-any-plans-after-assimilating-all-they-want/102443#102443)'
- Paul D. Waite's creative answer to '[Has the phrase 'Star Trek' ever been used in Star Trek?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102107/has-the-phrase-star-trek-ever-been-used-in-star-trek/102121#102121)'
- The Pop Machine's brilliantly creative answer to '[What's the relationship among the many uses of the name “Praxis” in sci-fi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99720/whats-the-relationship-among-the-many-uses-of-the-name-praxis-in-sci-fi/99721#99721)'

Comment: None of mine :(. And FYI Paul's answer is incorrect, they actually use the phrase Star Trek exactly, i'll post my answer later, so you can add it) :)

Comment: I just went to post my answer was all set up and then scrolled up to see that you posted the answer already! LMFAO! Your answer was the best answer to that question and you should have been awarded a correct answer, damn. You should change your answer to be your answer instead of his. Oh well. And thanks for the props on Wolf 359. You had an awesome question and answer recently. I remember one that I was going to put a bounty on, but I can't remember them. I should really post one of these, but I'm so busy right now with this deal I'm working on... +1 on Wolf 359 answer lol

Answer (score 5):

## Self-promotion alert

I stand by this one

[In Star Trek, do the Greek gods lack nipples?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/102947/in-star-trek-do-the-greek-gods-lack-nipples)

because nipples.

And because I like when I think I have an interesting question and then after some research, it ends up fascinating.

So, of course this one too, which was both fascinating and a lot of work to do.   But fun.

[What's the relationship among the many uses of the name "Praxis" in sci-fi?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99720/whats-the-relationship-among-the-many-uses-of-the-name-praxis-in-sci-fi) (hint: I answered in the form of a poem)

Answer (score 5):

**Best Answer:**

I'm surprised no one has mentioned Praxis's answer to [When was the Verteron Array built exactly and why wasn't it used against the Xindi when they were about to destroy earth?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95785/)

I only officially joined SFF this quarter, but I've been lurking around here for a while, and this is one of the nicest, most creative answers I have seen.

Answer (score 3):

I never get nominated for any of these, so I'm going to nominate a few of my own answers that I think are rather good.

First, I'd like to nominate my self answered question ["Does the general public know who superheroes really are in the Marvel Cinematic Universe?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/100804/does-the-general-public-know-who-superheroes-really-are-in-the-marvel-cinematic). I put a lot of effort into it and I'm happy to say it was received well.

Second, I'd like to nominate [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97033/why-arent-the-people-responsible-for-creating-ultron-arrested-at-the-end-of-ave/97037#97037) to the question ["Why aren't the people responsible for creating Ultron arrested at the end of Avengers: Age of Ultron?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97033/why-arent-the-people-responsible-for-creating-ultron-arrested-at-the-end-of-ave). This leans heavily on my knowledge of what (broadly speaking) will be happening next in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, as well as some (solid and evidence based) speculation about the details of *Captain America: Civil War*.

And finally, I feel that [my answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/95130/24087) to the question ["Are there any rules/guidelines regarding Spider-Man's appearance?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94295/are-there-any-rules-guidelines-regarding-spider-mans-appearance/) never got as much attention as it deserved - it's an interesting (and topical) question that, although potentially looking primarily opinion-based, actually had a definitive answer.

---

I'd also like to mention ["Elvish tattoo - can it be translated into English?"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/96984/elvish-tattoo-can-it-be-translated-into-english) as a great example of why I love this community.

Comment: +100 for the Elvish Tattoo one. Not only did we put our knowledge to good use, but also that it involved a great deal of work from our own [Jason Baker](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31051/jason-baker), as well as attracting a new, and rather valued [member](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/48975/isanae) to our community. I like, literally watched this question for like an entire day to watch the events unfold. It felt good to be a part of it.

Comment: @DrRDizzle : I added your "Does the general public know...?" question to my list of nominations.  So consider yourself nominated!  And nice work. :-)

Comment: I'd separate the Elvish tattoo one. I just feel like it should have a special mention of its own. In a way, we used our geek-ly talents for a good reason :)

Answer (score 2):

**Best Answer:**

Andrew Ferguson's answer to my question "[Reading order for the novels of R. A. Lafferty](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/97103/reading-order-for-the-novels-of-r-a-lafferty)".